# Creating a new Maven Scala project in Eclipse results in 4 errors

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, jar

**Edit 2:** I seem to have discovered the problem: the JAR files that were downloaded to my m2 repository are corrupt:

[image]

It seems to me that they could be causing the problems. But why are they corrupt? And how can I fix that?

**Edit:** I've ran `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` in the project, and it completed successfully... and introduced 5 additional errors:

[image]

On another PC I've created a Scala Maven project using the m2eclipse and Scala IDE plugins for Eclipse. I don't remember any errors. Then I pushed it to GitHub.

I then proceeded to clone the project on my laptop, but I was first greeted with this (error) message:

[image]

After selecting `yes`, what seemed to be the logical step, these errors appeared:

[image]

What's going on and how can I fix it?

(Linux, Elementary OS)

Comment: Sometimes there are glitches with Maven, make sure that library exists in .m2 folder. Also if it exists and still complains, delete it and force maven to re-download it. As for Scala Library path I assume you already set that one up.

Comment: After you cloned your project, did you try running `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` (which should re-build .classpath)?

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić: ran that, got 5 additional errors :) Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possibly a **difference in Scala versions used**. Scala IDE is usually based on specific version of Scala. Looks like your project pom.xml requires different version of Scala.

A solution is to either update your pom.xml to version of your IDE or upgrade the Scala IDE if possible.

The other possibility is that downloaded jars are corrupted.

Comment: Yes that's the case (still not sure if that's the main problem, I have yet to try to fix it). I use Ubuntu LTS which has very old packages. Scala reports its version as `2.9.1`. The IDE I installed is listed as requiring `2.10.x`. I'm not that eager to mess with my package management so I'll try to get a different version of the Scala IDE if that is possible.

Comment: What you actually want is same version of `Scala IDE` and scala libraries in your `pom.xml`. Your external installation has nothing to do with it, because `Scala IDE` uses it own

Comment: That's weird then, my Scala libraries are all the correct version specified in the POM...

Comment: Same version as Scala included with your IDE?

Comment: Looked up the Scala libraries included in the maven libraries dialogue, all the jars ended with `-2.10...`, so yeah I'm pretty sure that's a yes.

Comment: Last thing to check is that all dependencies are actually installed in your local Maven repository. This error  can be produced by a faulty jar.

Comment: Well the problem is still not solved though :/ I will try on another PC, if it doesn't happen, then I'll conclude it's some local bug and accept your answer, if not I will edit the question and search for other answers.

Comment: Maven file corruption usually is the result of timeouts while downloading. Do you have some kind of firewall?